# Magento 2 - Observer for shipping address change

Tags: magento2, event-observer

is there a way to create an observer which is listening to changes on the shipping address?

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try observing events :

1. customer_address_save_before
2. customer_address_save_after

**UPDATED**

For Orders:

1. sales_order_address_save_before
2. sales_order_address_save_after

Comment: does the same exist for orders?

Comment: I have updated the answer for orders, you can try those events.

Comment: do you know how to get the address from the observer?

Comment: You will get the object, try debug the object using xdebug

Comment: @L.Klmn how to get the address?